# How to specify both absolute and relative widths for table widths in iText with C#?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I want to produce a set of tables on a page which all have an absolute width of 500 and all have a last column with an absolute width of 100. However, I want to use relative widths to determine the widths of the other columns. Is there an easy way to do this?

Below is some sample code of a table. Is there anything I can add to make the last column with the 'e' in it an absolute width of 100 and have the first four columns maintaining their relative widths?

```
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(4);

    table.TotalWidth = 500f;
    table.LockedWidth = true;

    float[] widths = new float[] { 7f, 0.5f, 2f, 4f };            

    table.SetWidths(widths);         

    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("a"));
    cell.Rowspan = 2;

    table.AddCell(cell);

    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("b"));
    cell.Rowspan = 2;

    table.AddCell(cell);                       

    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("c"));

    table.AddCell(cell);

    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("e"));
    cell.Rowspan = 2;

    table.AddCell(cell);

    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("d"));

    table.AddCell(cell);

    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" "));
    cell.Colspan = 4;

    table.AddCell(cell);
```

Comment: Not possible. It's either absolute or relative, you'll have to calculate the widths.

Comment: Ok, so you can't split it up into 2 lines of code: with the first one specifying relative widths and then the next line of code specifying the final column width as an absolute width?

Comment: that's what Paulo said.